# how to access @odata property in javascript object?

Tags: javascript, odata

The API data object looks like this:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('xxx')/contacts",
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/contacts?skip=15&top=5",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"EQAAABYAAAD3oaJTZHHCT4+90fu7tI+0AAABdDz4\"",
            "id": "AAMkADBmNzg3Zjcw
```

etc..

I want to access the `@odata.nextLink` property but if I use `data.@odata.nextlink` I get 'Invalid or unexpected token' on the `@` symbol.

Comment: Use bracket notation. `data["@odata.nextlink"]`

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for and it works

Comment: Something easy to stumble upon is that the the property is actually named `@odata.context` and not just `@odata`...

Comment: For me the @odata property was in an intermediate object so I had to put everything between brackets eg. `data['Courses@odata.count']` (Courses being the entity I wanted to count)
Hope this will help some.